# c# How to use winforms fullscreen with System.Graphics?

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics, fullscreen, gdi+

I need to make the winforms gdi+ application unfold to fullscreen

I draw all interface elements with this code.

```
e.Graphics.DrawImage(MatheMage.Properties.Resources.ChooseMenu, 0, 300);
```

And I get something like that
[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T5Wed.png)

And if I using this code

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.TopMost = true;
    this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
    this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
}
```

I get something like that [image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FHuZz.png)

I need all the elements to stretch along with the window

Comment: There are many method overloads of `DrawImage` that allow you to specify a target size of the drawn image (the image will be scaled to the specified size): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.drawimage?view=netframework-4.7.2

For example, you might use this overload: `DrawImage(Image, Rectangle, Rectangle, GraphicsUnit)`

Comment: I need to unfold the form, not the individual images. And for any screen resolution. Currently, the resolution of the form is 640: 480

Comment: Yeah, but you draw everything yourself. So if the form (the drawing surface) changes its size, you have to redraw, taking the new size of the form into account (WinForms controls do exactly the same - they redraw their graphic representation whenever their size changes). My knowledge about WinForms is rather rusty, but perhaps there is a canvas-like control that automatically scales the stuff drawn onto it?

Comment: If I maximize the window, then the entire area that was not drawn in the form 640: 480 remains white.

Comment: That is because you either don't redraw, or you redraw un-scaled (not taking the changed form size into account) when the form size changes. Again, as i said in my previous comment: If the form (the drawing surface) changes its size, you have to redraw, taking the new size of the form into account (and scale while drawing the elements as mentioned in my first comment).

Comment: Sorry, I do not know English well for this, I did not understand your past message. That is, if I understood correctly, I need to draw them at a certain point and multiply this point and size by the height and width of the form. That is, there is no method for simply increasing everything?

Answer (score 0):

Try this inside your form load method after you change WindowState

```
this.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch;
```

Comment: That would require setting the BackgroundImage property.

Answer (score 0):

As you already draw with the graphics object, just use the ScaleTransform method.

```
//save the current Transformation state of the graphics object.
var transState = e.Graphics.Save();

// Setting keepAspectRatio to false will scale your image to full screen.
// setting it to true will fill either the width or the height. you might need to use TranslateTransform method to move the image to the center.
bool keepAspectRatio = false;

// Calculate width and height ratios
// if you currently render everything to 640px/480px, you can take those dimensions instead of the Image size I used to calculate the ratios.
float widthRatio = this.DisplayRectangle.Width / MatheMage.Properties.Resources.ChooseMenu.Width;
float heightRatio = this.DisplayRectangle.Height / MatheMage.Properties.Resources.ChooseMenu.Height;

if(keepAspectratio)
{
    // If aspect ratio shall be kept: choose the smaller scale for both dimensions
    if(widthRatio > heightRatio)
    {
        widthRatio = heightRatio;
    }
    else
    {
        heightRatio = widthRatio;
    }
}

// Scale the graphics object.
e.Graphics.ScaleTransform(widthRatio, heightRatio);

// Draw your stuff as before.
e.Graphics.DrawImage(MatheMage.Properties.Resources.ChooseMenu, 0, 300);

//finally restor the old transformation state of the graphics object.
e.Graphics.Restore(transState);
```

Hope this gets you going. Be aware that the code is untested.